# Jenkins pipeline timeout not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using a declarative pipeline to execute a multi-stage ETL process. Since single steps or the whole pipeline might exceed the default 5-minute timeout, we would like to overwrite the timeout behaviour. 
We have tested different kind of approaches and the only one that is working is when there are multiple commands in one steps that take less than five minutes each.

This pipeline works fine:

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    options {
      timeout(time: 6, unit: 'MINUTES') 
    }

    stages{        
        stage('Input')
        {
            steps{               
                do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
                do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
                do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pipeline fails:

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    options {
      timeout(time: 6, unit: 'MINUTES') 
    }

    stages{        
        stage('Input')
        {
            steps{               
                do_something_that_takes_6_minutes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE: Error log

```
an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@73520a76
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@74c71fe2
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@729ea185
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@600e8138
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@5f210416
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.thread
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution@2612450a
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution.body
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution@2f312540
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.step
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@2dac466b
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.thread
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution@32ef2900
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter.this$0
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter@6db6c39f
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.returnAddress
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@70c5735
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.TryBlockEnv@3a0cb158
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureCallEnv@438eac94
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@60dd23a0
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@6670740f
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.TryBlockEnv@240d9fda
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5c46e790
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7d6f7891
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@3dbfe014
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@4637c092
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@4c4db8b4
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@fa9e73d
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureCallEnv@657de1be
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@39af5105
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@4ddc2645
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@440311a7
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@bcfe902
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@2f059f6a
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@514f2c
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5dd25a36
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@4ce3fc81
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1f3e1a2b
in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@f8eca2a
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4d7407fc
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4d7407fc
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.UNIXProcess
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor386.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor386.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:477)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:453)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:440)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:367)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

UPDATE:

It seems like somehow the reason was the function that we used to call our python scripts:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def exec(cmd) {
  println cmd
  def process = new ProcessBuilder([ "sh", "-c", cmd])
                                    .directory(new File("/tmp"))
                                    .redirectErrorStream(true) 
                                    .start()
  process.inputStream.eachLine {println it}
  process.waitForOrKill(1000000) /* 16 min */
  if ( process.exitValue() == 0 )
                    {
                     println "return code: ${ process.exitValue()}"
                    }
  else {
                     println "return code: ${ process.exitValue()}"
                     emailext body: "Error Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}",
                       to: 'xxx',
                       recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
                       subject: "Error: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}"
                     throw new Exception("Error")
                     }

}
```

Not sure why, but it somehow led to the NotSerializable errors. For the time being, we execute the scripts via shell and this works fine.

Comment: Jenkins does check for that (if you work with Serializable objects). Enclosing it in a @NonCPS annotated function should be enough. Also the Log makes it clear that "java.lang.UNIXProcess" is not Serializable (neither it nor the abstract Process parent class is).

Answer (score 1):

Most interesting,
it seems that options on any level would be applied to each separate step. [So the step is defined as](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#step):

> A single task. Fundamentally, a step tells Jenkins what to do at a
>   particular point in time (or "step" in the process). For example, to
>   execute the shell command make use the sh step: sh 'make'. When a
>   plugin extends the Pipeline DSL, [ 1] that typically means the plugin
>   has implemented a new step.

Options regardless of the level on which they are defined will be applied to each step separately.

It seems that to fix this you would have to use the [script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) tag.

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    options {
      timeout(time: 6, unit: 'MINUTES') 
    }

    stages{        
        stage('Input')
        {
            steps{
                script {               
                    do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
                    do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
                    do_something_that_takes_3_minutes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The pipeline that causes problems is the second that I posted, not the first. I tried to add the script tag to the second pipeline script that I posted, but it didn't work.

Comment: could post the text to the comment since it's too long, please see below